# Convert from cartesian to polar or spherical coordinates in order to show functions belong to $L^p$ space or Sobolev space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

> Q1. Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{\log x} $ and $\Omega = (0,\frac{1}{2})$. Show that $f \in L^p (\Omega)$ for any $p \geq 1$ and $f' \in L^p(\Omega)$ only for $p=1$.

> Q2. Show that $g(x) = \log( \log ( 1 + {|x|}^{-1} ) $ belongs to $W^{1,n}(D)$ for $n>1$ where $D = B(0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ .

The hint I got for both questions was to use polar or spherical coordinates. I tried integrating $f(x)$ for Q1 by u-substituion with $u= \log(x) $ which gave me a sum of terms. How do I go about showing $f(x)$ is integrable for all $p \geq 1$ with that? I differentiated $g(x)$ wrt $x_i$ for Q2 which wasn't very helpful in seeing a workaround to using polar coordinates. Q2 is a generalization of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3890441/prove-that-ux-log-log-left1-frac1-vert-x-vert-right-in-h1b0-1). Any tips please.

Comment: Concerning Q1: $f^p$ has a continuous extension onto the compact set $\left[ 0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$ and is hence integrable. In case of $f'$ you can substitute $u = \log(x)$

Comment: I was able to show $f' \in L^1$ but not able to do it for $p>1$. The continuous extension part is not something I know or have seen.